# Pagination error with JQuery / PHP values

Tags: php, jquery

**Greetings,**

*I am building my homepage,and i am learning PHP and javascript.* *Here i am* **trying to integrate a pagination system using a JQuery script that sends a value call to a php function called fetch.php to fetch articles by categories.**

*When the php function is called it gives back an error :* **PDOException:  Syntax error: Undeclared variable: $start_from in fetch.php on line 20.**

Can JQuery send multiple values to my php function ,so i grab the value from (pagination id) and send it with the string value ? I also looking for a suggestion on how it would be easier and correct.
av
Please do not angry on my code ,i know i have to use prepared statement to avoid sql and xss ,but my goal is to make it working and learn basic aspects and from a working "alfa version" move on to ameliorate update and secure my code.

Thank you all in advance !

```
<?php
require_once "pdoconfig.php";

//PAGINATION
$limit = 1; 

$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$rs_result = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT (id) FROM articles WHERE categorie_id = :q');
$row = $rs_result-> fetch();
$total_records = $row[0];  
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit); 

if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit; 
  
//FETCH POSTS
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, short_details, pubdate FROM articles WHERE categorie_id = :q LIMIT $start_from, $limit') ;
$stmt->execute(array(':q' => $_GET['q']));

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<div class='card mb-4'>" . "<div class='card-body'>";
  echo "<h2 class='card-title'>";
  echo $row['title'] . "</h2>";
  echo "<div class='card-footer text-muted'>";
  echo $row['pubdate'];
  echo "</h2>";
  echo "<p class='card-text'>";
  echo $row['short_details'];
  echo "</p>";
  echo '<p><a href="view.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read More</a></p>';
  echo "</div>" . "</div>" . "</div>";
 
};
```

The JQuery script that calls the php function:

```
<script>
    <!-- ajax: fetch posts by cat --> 
    function showPostCat(str) {
      if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","fetch.php?q="+str,true );
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Here is a part of my html from the index.php

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
  <div class="col-md-8" id="txtHint">
    <br>
    <!-- Blog -->
...
...
<!-- pagination section--> 
<div class="col-md-8" id="pagination">
 <ul class='pagination text-center'>
<?php if(!empty($total_pages)):for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++):  
            if($i == 1):?>
            <li class='active'  id="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href='page.php?page=<?php echo $i;?>'><?php           echo $i;?></a></li> 
            <?php else:?>
            <li id="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href='page.php?page=<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
        <?php endif;?>          
<?php endfor;endif;?> 
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: i need to somehow get the pagination div value with my JQuery script that will pass it as a value to my fetch.php but i did not found out how to get and pass a second value

Answer (score 1):

In your codes, you only pass the value to "q", if you want to pass multiple parameters (e.g. parameters2, value=str2, please use the following syntax:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","fetch.php?q="+str + "&parameter2" + str2 ,true );
```

Comment: Thx Ken ! Actually i can t insert a clear script code here in comments ,i actually modified to this: `
<script>
function showPostCat(str) {
...
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById("pagination").innerHTML = "";
 
    return;
  } else {
    ...
    xmlhttp.open("GET","fetch.php?q="+str,+str,true );
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>'` since it takes to documents now it is still not sending the values

Comment: Since you want to pass multiple parameters to the php (e.g. two parameters), please modify xmlhttp.open ("GET","fetch.php?q="+str,+str,true ) to xmlhttp.open ("GET","fetch.php?q="+str + "&q2="+str2,true ).